# Xcode can't find header files in xcode10.3

Tags: xcode, macos, configuration-files, glad

I'm following a tutorial to learn opengl on Xcode 10.3.
But I always get <'glad/glad.h' file not found> issue.
I can't find where have problem.

(1)
I use cmake to install glfw and use glad web generator to generate glad.zip.
I put glfw headers in /usr/local/include/GLFW
I put glfw lbs in /usr/local/lib
I put glad header (glad.h) in /usr/local/include/glad

(2)
try one
add /usr/local/include (recursive and none-recursive both tried) to header search path

and add libs to lib search path...

try two
I add /usr/local/include/glad (recursive and none-recursive both tried)
I add /usr/local/include/GLFW (recursive and none-recursive both tried)

and add libs to lib search path...

both get 'glad/glad.h' file not found issue

Comment: `GLAD` does not work that way; it requires you start up a webservice then generates the proper header files.

Comment: Yes...I use glad web generator to generate glad.zip and unzip it...then I put glad.h into /usr/local/include/glad and import glad.c into my project.

Comment: What type project is it? (eg. `C++`, `C`, etc.)

Comment: command line tool

Comment: by the way.if i import glfw header files and glad file into my project ,it works.but i need add them into BuildPhase->Header config. and change import script from #include <glad/glad.h> to #include "glad.h"...